# get_post_meta() is not working inside order email (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the custom field value in order mail but its not showing inside the order mail while this is working with plugin(WooCommerce Email Test). Every custom field value are displaying here with this plugin.

This is my code (Inside email-order-details.php):

```
<tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                   <?php if($total['label'] == "Shipping:" || $total['label'] == "Verzending:"){ ?>

                   <?php } elseif($total['label'] == "Subtotal:" || $total['label'] == "Subtotaal:") {
                   $oid = $order->get_id(); ?>
                   <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Subtotaal"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php $order_st=get_post_meta($oid, 'order_subtotal', true); echo "<span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."</span>".$order_st."245.00"; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $trans_method=get_post_meta($oid, 'trans_method', true); if($trans_method == 'pickup'){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Transportkosten"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "<span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."</span>0.00"; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Afhalen"; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Totaal ex BTW"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php $teb=get_post_meta($oid, 'order_subtotal', true); echo "<span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."</span>".$teb; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($trans_method == 'deliverybypostcode'){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Transportkosten"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"><?php $transcost=get_post_meta($oid, 'tran_cost', true); echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();  ?></span><?php echo money_format("%.2n", $transcost); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Bezorgen op postcode:"; ?> <?php $postcode=get_post_meta($oid, 'trans_location', true);
                    $place_dis=get_post_meta($oid, 'trans_distance', true);
                    $mcrane=get_post_meta($oid, 'mounted_crane', true);
                     echo $postcode[0]." ".$place_dis."</br>";
    if($mcrane == "Yes"){
        echo "Transport: "."Met autolaadkraan"."</td></tr>";
    }else{
        echo "Transport: "."Zonder autolaadkraan"."</td></tr>";
    } ?>
    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Totaal ex BTW"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php $os_total=get_post_meta($oid, 'order_subtotal', true);
                         $tcost=get_post_meta($oid, 'tran_cost', true);
                        $ot_cost=$os_total+money_format("%.2n", $tcost);
                          echo "<span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."</span>". money_format("%.2n", $ot_cost); ?></td>
                    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
                   <?php } elseif($total['label'] == "BTW:"){ 
                    $oid1 = $order->get_id();
                    ?>
                   <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php $ttax = get_post_meta($oid1, 'order_total_tax', true); echo "<span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>".get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()."</span>".$ttax; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                     <?php } elseif($total['label'] == "Total:" || $total['label'] == "Totaal:"){ ?>
                     <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo "Totaal incl. BTW"; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php }else{ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
```

Please tell me what thing I am doing wrong here (Simply I just want to display custom fields value also inside order mail)

Comment: Thanks for your response #George.                                                            But I am saving some values ​​in this table also wp_postmeta and getting this by order id

Comment: Its working fine with Email test plugin but I am not getting values inside order mail.

Comment: please check in DB with order id values stores in post_meta table?

Comment: You mean i have to save value in this table woocommerce_order_itemmeta and then show it from this table.

Comment: no. seems you are doing correctly

Comment: just check whether values order stored in table for that order

Comment: Actually order_id and post_id are same in database thats why i am displaying this using get_post_meta() by order id

Comment: Yes its getting store.

Comment: You know its working with testing email plugin, but i am not getting value in order mail.

Comment: location of this file `email-order-details.php` to `themes\your-theme\woocommerce\emails` or child theme?

Comment: Yes this is themes\your-theme\woocommerce\emails

Comment: Hello #George, Did you find any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was updating my custom values ​​on Thank You page due to which our custom value was updated in the database after sending the order email.

Therefore I was not getting the custom value in the order mail.

Now I updated Our custom value before sending the order mail and it's working fine.

Thank's Guys for your response!